# Mod Rewrite code with out changing the url in address bar

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond, directoryindex

I When I call http://www.mysite.in/abc/xyz it shoud show up http://www.mysite.in/abc/xyz/index.php but the url shout not change in address bar and it should work with out "/" in the address. Please any one help me with .htaccess code for apache 2.2

Note: It should not list the directory content it should show up the page.. SEO Friendly URL.

Thanks
Sreekanth

Comment: You need to give more information. What's changing? What is your current config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how i did it
Added the bellow code to root folder .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(abx/xyz.html)/?$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

And added the bellow code to the .htaccess file in side the xyz.html folder

```
DirectorySlash Off
Directoryindex index.php
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `DirectoryIndex index.php` and `Options -Indexes`.

Both shoud be default configurations on any Apache / PHP installation.

Something seems broken in your configuration.